# Postgres now() returns +03 timezone but show timezone returns GMT

Tags: postgresql, timezone

```
prompt$ date

Mon Oct  7 17:32:24 UTC 2013

prompt$ psql -U postgres

postgres=# show timezone;

 TimeZone
----------  
 GMT 
(1 row)

postgres=# select now();

              now
-------------------------------
 2013-10-07 20:32:42.354384+03
(1 row)
```

Why is it returning it in +03 timezone format? What am I obviously missing here?

EDIT: I solved the problem, but a question still remains. Here is what happened:

I had changed the system's OS timezone, without restarting the postgres server. Previous OS timezone was indeed +03. After I restarted postgres, it worked correctly. But it is a strange situation: postgresql.conf has not any timezone explicitly defined and the client (psql) should should always output timestamps in the timezone reported by "show timezone". So there is still this unexplained question:

Why psql was reporting GMT as timezone setting but displayed timestamps in the OS new timezone. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: I have solved the problem but still not satisfied with the behaviour I saw. See my edit

Comment: Unless you have timezone configured in postgresql.conf, a system default time zone will be used - the one configured at the time of postgresql server startup. "psql" will show timestamptz-s according to "timezone" setting (with default value == server's default), regardless of client's time zone selection.

One more thing: watch out for ALTER USER ... SET timezone to '...';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly odd behavior, largely because I would have expected `show timezone` to show the same timezone as now() showed.  My recommendation is try to reproduce the situation and then email the PostgreSQL list or file a bug report.  It sounds like you might be able to cause this by changing your system timezone while PostgreSQL is running.  A reload or restart might fix the problem.

I also second the notion of watching out for `ALTER USER ... SET TIMEZONE`, but on top of that you can also `ALTER DATABASE ... SET TIMEZONE` and even `ALTER FUNCTION ... SET TIMEZONE`